# .Net Maui [RelayCommand] fails to compile if method name starts with a lowercase character?

Tags: .net-maui, maui-community-toolkit

New to .Net MAUI and am using version 8.0.0 of the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.3.3

In my XAML, I have a button:

```
<Button 
   Text="Add"
   Command="{Binding data_addCommand}"
   />
```

In my ViewModel, I have the following method:

```
[RelayCommand]
private void data_add()
{

}
```

When I build the compiler fails with the following:

```
Error   CS0102  The type '[my_viewmodel_name]' already contains a definition for 'data_addCommand'
```

However, just out of desperation, I changed the XML to:

```
<Button 
   Text="Add"
   Command="{Binding Data_addCommand}"
   />
```

... and in my ViewModel:

```
[RelayCommand]
private void Data_add()
{

}
```

**The only difference being the method name in the Binding command and method name in the ViewModel start with an uppercase "D" instead of a lowercase "d".**

When I build, it completes successfully! - ?? -- Did I miss something in the documentation that states the method name for a [RelayCommand] must start with an Uppercase letter?

I do recall that when using the [ObservableProperty] attribute, the generated properties will automatically use an UpperCamelCase format for their names.  However, I do not recall seeing anything with regard to the [RelayCommand].  I am assuming this is the case (excuse the pun) and the [RelayCommand] attribute will work the same as an [ObservableProperty] attribute -- that is, will use an UpperCamelCase format for the method name -- hence, must start with an Uppercase character.

Just wanting to know if there is anything "official" that documents this behavior as it threw me for a loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using UpperCamelCase format is right, but I think the data_addCommand might duplicate which caused the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the MVVM CommunityToolkit, that is, when you include the NuGet package "CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" into your project and then use the [RelayCommand] attribute to decorate a method name, the toolkit auto-generates a backing field **that uses lowercase**.  The toolkit will also auto-generate an IRelayCommand object.

For example, if you have the following code:

```
[RelayCommand]
private void method_name()
{

}
```

The following code will be auto-generated by the CommunityToolkit:

```
// A backing field ...
private global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.RelayCommand? method_nameCommand;

// An IRelayCommand object ...
public global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.IRelayCommand method_nameCommand => method_nameCommand ??= new global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.RelayCommand(new global::System.Action(method_name));
```

The auto-generated code causes the backing field name AND IRelayCommand object name to be the same, which in turn causes the compiler error.

Now, if you change your method name to use an uppercase character, i.e.:

```
[RelayCommand]
private void Method_name()
{

}
```

The auto-generated code will look as follows and will compile successfully.

```
// A backing field ...
private global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.RelayCommand? method_nameCommand;

// An IRelayCommand object ...
public global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.IRelayCommand Method_nameCommand => method_nameCommand ??= new global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.RelayCommand(new global::System.Action(Method_name));
```

So - the (undocumented) rule of thumb appears to be:

**When using the [RelayCommand] attribute to decorate a method, make sure the first character of your method name is uppercase.**

Comment: But this is terrible if you need a canExecute condition. The whole decoration thing is a terrible design choice by the community toolkit.